# Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:

Tags: javafx

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ginkgo</groupId>
<artifactId>csgo-cfg-helper-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>16</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
    <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jlinkImageName>csgo_cfg_helper</jlinkImageName>
                <launcher>launcher</launcher>
                <mainClass>com.ginkgo.csgo.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.ginkgo.csgo.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

1. My Operating System: MacOs Big Sur 11.4
2. JDK: openjdk-16.0.1

I want to make a .dmg or .pkg file using command *mvn clean jfx:native*, however, it doesn't work.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:jar (jar) on project csgo-cfg-helper-client: Execution jar of goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:jar failed: Plugin com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path /Users/hll/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-16.0.1/Contents/Home/../lib/ant-javafx.jar -> [Help 1]

Is it Java Version too high? jLink work well and generate module success.

How should i do? This is my first time to bulid a JavaFX project. I find the same question in stackoverflow, but no useful answer.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to follow an ancient tutorial. Just start with the official docs and not some crap pulled from the internet. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ And for packaging you app have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage